# Joomla Module custom HTML WYSIWYG keeps stripping off absolute URL

Tags: php, joomla

Somehow Joomla WYSIWYG keeps stripping off absolute URL even though I place them inside places such as src attribute or image!

Is there a way to ensure it doesn't get stripped off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a built in behavior in the core Joomla editor. Switch to JCE. It's a better editor and it's free (unless you want the fancy plugins too, but they are not needed).

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors/88